# How to use CMAKE_MODULE_PATH correctly on windows

Tags: cmake

What is the proper way to modify this variable so that CMake can find the appropriate modules that projects specify as requirements? It seems to be autogenerated and I cannot find environment variables that would modify this path in any way. I also am hard pressed to find documentation that explains this well; only instructions to "install" CMake packages with no details on how exactly that can be accomplished.

Comment: You want to set additional locations for CMake to search for stuff? Then use [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).

Comment: That's correct. However, how can I actually set that variable? Is it an environment variable or what?

Comment: I also want to set it for all projects.

Comment: Doesn’t it work to add the directories to the PATH environment variable then?

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` would be specified per build tree, either by adding it in the cmake-gui before configuring or via cmd: `cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING="C:/dev/foo" …`.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 8):

You can extend or set the module path like so:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "some path to modules")
```

or:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "path")
```

Just like you can any other (list) variable.

Answer (score 0):

@xaav Expanding upon @utopia'S answer:

> "*CMake will look for modules in the directories specified by
> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH; if it cannot find it there, it will look in the
> Modules subdirectory.*"
>
> -Master CMake, by K. Matrin & B. Hoffman, pg. 38

The book doesn't do too a good job of explaining where this directory is though.

On Windows, you'll find it in:

`C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.21\Modules\`

(for x64-bit CMake vers. 3.21 on Windows 10, e.g.). In general on Windows, it will be in

`<your_cmake_install_directory>\share\cmake-<your_version>\Modules\`

Furthermore, modules are files ending in `.cmake` and can be run directly from the command line by

`cmake -P module.cmake`

You can find a copy of the book [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuperCV/Book/master/CMake/mastering-cmake.pdf). Its a fair starting point, but it's 500 pages long and should be read kind of like a novel. To really understand CMake, I'd dive through the online documentation examples and projects others have posted on GitHub.