# Adding ffmpeg to clion project

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake, clion

I would liket to add ffmpeg to Clion but I have some problems with it.
My MakeLists.txt looks liek this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ffmpeg)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/)
include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/libavutil/)
include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/libaccodec/)
include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/libavdevice/)
include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/libavfilter/)
include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/libavformat/)

include_directories(libs/ffmpeg/include/)
link_directories(libs/ffmpeg/lib/)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


add_executable(ffmpeg main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        ffmpeg
        avcodec
        avdevice
        avfilter
        avformat
        avresample
        avutil
        postproc
        swresample
        swscale
)
```

I am not sure if I added the libraries and includes in the right way, beacause in my simple main.cpp it can't resolve avcodec_configuration().
My project layout looks as follows:

```
  ffmpeg
    -libs
      -include
        -libavcodec
        .
        .
        .
      -lib
        -avcodec.lib
    -main.cpp
```

EDIT: 
Now all includes are found by the compiler. BUt if I compile I get following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lavresample
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [ffmpeg.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ffmpeg.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\ffmpeg.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'ffmpeg.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ffmpeg.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: The project layout you show doesn't match the directories in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: "my simple main.cpp it can't resolve avcodec_configuration()." - Is there is a error during **compiling** (like "couldn't find a header file") or one during **linking** ("unresolved symbol")? Please, elaborate. **Exact** error message would be a preferrable way for express the problem.

Comment: I managed to get it working. BUt if I compile it I get this error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lavresample
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [ffmpeg.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ffmpeg.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\ffmpeg.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'ffmpeg.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ffmpeg.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to hardcode paths to the headers/libraries in your `CMakeLists.txt`; this is not portable.

- Search for a ready `FindFFmpeg.cmake` (maybe [this one](https://github.com/snikulov/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindFFmpeg.cmake) will work?),
- add it to your project directory (e.g. into a `cmake/` subdirectory),
- and [connect it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177196/how-to-use-cmake-module-path-correctly-on-windows) to [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html). E.g. `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")`.
- Then refer to `${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}`, `${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${FFMPEG_DEFINITIONS}`.

Sometimes you have to fix up the `FindXXX.cmake` modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to include the precompiled ffmpeg library to cmake project by creating find cmake scripts and including them in main CMakeLists.txt.

Full example is here : https://github.com/tomkordic/Java-native-HTTP/tree/master/src/main/cpp

In my project a FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY and FFMPEG_LIB_DIRECTORY are passed by gradle build script you can set these manually or discover them in some other way.

FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY is a path to ffmpeg installation include directory, in my case:

```
/mnt/7fab2260-fb19-41a7-ac7c-816bab2f3b92/install/ffmpeg_build/include
```

FFMPEG_LIB_DIRECTORY is a path to ffmpeg installation lib directory, in my case:

```
/mnt/7fab2260-fb19-41a7-ac7c-816bab2f3b92/install/ffmpeg_build/lib
```

Make sure to set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to the directory where your find cmake scripts are located.

Build system is for ubuntu 18.04.